# How to Configure JW Player to play immediately without finishing to buffer

Tags: wordpress, jwplayer

How to Configure JW Player to play immediately without finishing to buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the comment issue i found when use JW flash player.

I found one solution of it.

Open "player.xml" file in your wordpress plugin or JW Flash player config

Set the smoothing flashvar to false.
Set the bufferlength flashvar to 1.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with how your video was encoded. This tool might fix your issue - http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/qtindexswapper-2/

Comment: I am using .flv and mp4 files for site and its 1.34 min
However its not loading fast.

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running this?

Comment: I am doing that on our server.
sorry i can't give you link .

Comment: We need to see a link in order to debug properly.